# Android Studio, SQLite, No Such Column Issue

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

Below is the error I'm getting:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{groceryproject.jacob.com.recipelist/groceryproject.jacob.com.recipelist.RecipeList}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: prep_time (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT id, recipe_name, servings, prep_time, cook_time, ingredients, directions FROM recipes WHERE id=?
```

This is after I've uninstalled the app and cleared all data to make sure I don't have a previous database messing me up. Below is the code for my database class:

```
package groceryproject.jacob.com.recipelist;

/**
 * Created by Jacob on 11/12/2016.
 */
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;

    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class RecipeDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "recipeManager";

    // Contacts table name
    private static final String TABLE_RECIPES = "recipes";

    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "recipe_name";
    private static final String KEY_COOK_TIME = "cook_time";
    private static final String KEY_PREP_TIME = "prep_time";
    private static final String KEY_SERVINGS = "servings";
    private static final String KEY_INGREDIENTS = "ingredients";
    private static final String KEY_DIRECTIONS = "directions";

    public RecipeDB(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_RECIPES + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_SERVINGS + " TEXT," + " TEXT," + KEY_COOK_TIME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_INGREDIENTS + " TEXT," + KEY_DIRECTIONS + " TEXT" + ")";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_RECIPES);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }



    void addRecipe(Recipe recipe) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, recipe.getRecipeName()); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_SERVINGS, recipe.getServings()); // Contact Phone
        values.put(KEY_PREP_TIME, recipe.getPrepTime());
        values.put(KEY_COOK_TIME, recipe.getCookTime());

        //Next few lines turns an array list of strings into one string seperated by tabs
        String directionsConcat = "";
        String ingedientsConcat = "";

        if(recipe.getIngredients() != null) {
            StringBuilder ingred = new StringBuilder();
            for (String s : recipe.getIngredients()) {
                ingred.append(s);
                ingred.append("\t");
            }
            ingedientsConcat = ingred.toString();
        }

        if(recipe.getDirections() != null) {
            StringBuilder direct = new StringBuilder();
            for (String s : recipe.getDirections()) {
                direct.append(s);
                direct.append("\t");
            }
            directionsConcat = direct.toString();
        }

        values.put(KEY_INGREDIENTS, ingedientsConcat);
        values.put(KEY_DIRECTIONS, directionsConcat);


        db.insert(TABLE_RECIPES, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }


    Recipe getRecipe(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_RECIPES, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                        KEY_NAME, KEY_SERVINGS, KEY_PREP_TIME, KEY_COOK_TIME, KEY_INGREDIENTS, KEY_DIRECTIONS },
                        KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null); //This line is where the error points to
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        List<String> directionsList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> ingredientsList = new ArrayList<>();

        String ingredients = cursor.getString(5);
        String directions = cursor.getString(6);


        if (directions != null){
            if(directions.contains("\t")) {
                directionsList = Arrays.asList(directions.split("\t"));
            }
            else{
                directionsList = Arrays.asList(directions);
            }
        }

        if (ingredients != null){
            if(ingredients.contains("\t")) {
                ingredientsList = Arrays.asList(ingredients.split("\t"));
            }
            else{
                ingredientsList = Arrays.asList(ingredients);
            }
        }

        Recipe recipe = new Recipe(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),
                cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), ingredientsList, directionsList);
        return recipe;
    }

    public List<Recipe> getAllRecipes() {
        List<Recipe> recipeList = new ArrayList<Recipe>();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_RECIPES;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);


        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Recipe recipe = new Recipe();

                recipe.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                recipe.setRecipeName(cursor.getString(1));
                recipe.setServingSize(cursor.getString(2));
                recipe.setPrepTime(cursor.getString(3));
                recipe.setCookTime(cursor.getString(4));

                List<String> directionsList = new ArrayList<>();
                List<String> ingredientsList = new ArrayList<>();

                String ingredients = cursor.getString(5);
                String directions = cursor.getString(6);


                if (directions != null){
                    if(directions.contains("\t")) {
                        directionsList = Arrays.asList(directions.split("\t"));
                    }
                    else{
                        directionsList = Arrays.asList(directions);
                    }
                }


                if (ingredients != null){
                    if(ingredients.contains("\t")) {
                        ingredientsList = Arrays.asList(ingredients.split("\t"));
                    }
                    else{
                        ingredientsList = Arrays.asList(ingredients);
                    }
                }

                recipe.setIngredients(ingredientsList);
                recipe.setDirections(directionsList);

                recipeList.add(recipe);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }


        return recipeList;
    }


    public int updateRecipe(Recipe recipe) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, recipe.getRecipeName()); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_SERVINGS, recipe.getServings()); // Contact Phone
        values.put(KEY_PREP_TIME, recipe.getPrepTime());
        values.put(KEY_COOK_TIME, recipe.getCookTime());

        //Next few lines turns an array list of strings into one string seperated by tabs
        String directionsConcat = "";
        String ingedientsConcat = "";

        if(recipe.getIngredients() != null) {
            StringBuilder ingred = new StringBuilder();
            for (String s : recipe.getIngredients()) {
                ingred.append(s);
                ingred.append("\t");
            }
            ingedientsConcat = ingred.toString();
        }

        if(recipe.getDirections() != null) {
            StringBuilder direct = new StringBuilder();
            for (String s : recipe.getDirections()) {
                direct.append(s);
                direct.append("\t");
            }
            directionsConcat = direct.toString();
        }

        values.put(KEY_INGREDIENTS, ingedientsConcat);
        values.put(KEY_DIRECTIONS, directionsConcat);

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_RECIPES, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(recipe.getID()) });
    }


    public void deleteRecipe(Recipe recipe) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_RECIPES, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(recipe.getID()) });
        db.close();
    }



    public int getRecipeCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_RECIPES;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }



}
```

The issue is caused when I call `getRecipe()` from my main Activity class:

```
package groceryproject.jacob.com.recipelist;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RecipeList extends AppCompatActivity{
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private int REQUEST_CODE=1;

    //private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

    //TODO: Create a new taskbar
    //TODO: Create a navigaton bar.
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        RecipeDB dbHelper = new RecipeDB(this);

        /*
        if(savedInstanceState != null){
            recipes = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("savedRecipes");
        }
        */



        ArrayList<String> one = new ArrayList<>();
        one.add("Test");

        Recipe testRecipe = new Recipe("Name", "Four slices",  "40", "80", one, one);

        dbHelper.addRecipe(testRecipe);
        Recipe testTwo = dbHelper.getRecipe(1); //This is where it breaks


        List<Recipe> recipes = dbHelper.getAllRecipes();
        recipes.add(testTwo); //This is to prove the adapter is working


        String log = "No results";
        for (Recipe rn : recipes){
            log = "Id: " + rn.getID() + ", Name: " + rn.getRecipeName();
        }
        Log.d("Name, ", log);
        //This log is printing no results when the app actually runs


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipe_list);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list_recycler_view);


        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);


        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(recipes);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);




    }
```

The cursor line in `getRecipe()` is where the error log is pointing to. It only happens when I call `getRecipe()`. If I was to create a list from calling `getAllRecipes()` instead, and pass that to the adapter, it doesn't crash on start up but the ArrayList is also empty.

I know the adapter works because if I manually add it to the array list recipes it appears on screen correctly. It's the database that's causing this problem.

I've been working at this for days, and have tried looking at many similar issues on SO, and I just feel stuck. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE` variable, I don't see a preptime key in there. And Contacts is a strange name for a Recipe table variable....

```
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_RECIPES + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_SERVINGS + " TEXT," + " TEXT," + KEY_COOK_TIME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_INGREDIENTS + " TEXT," + KEY_DIRECTIONS + " TEXT" + ")";
```

After you add the column, you need to update the `DATABASE_VERSION` as well to reflect those changes.

Comment: Thank you, I feel a bit silly. And yeah, contacts is a strange name. Since this is my first time using SQL I've been following a tutorial. I created the class entirely on my own the first time following the guide but couldn't get it working. So I copied and translated (missed this one) out of desperation after days of failure. I just didn't realize I was so close to the answer...Thank you again!

Comment: There are a bunch of libraries that exist for making SQLite easier. RealmDB is a popular one, for example. So is SugarORM

Answer (score 0):

you didn't add `KEY_PREP_TIME` in your oncreate command